# access hashmap in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

```
         <c:forEach var = "cart" items= "${cartx.items}"> 
            <tr bgcolor="${(i%2) ? "#EFF3FB" : "White" }">
                <td><c:out value = "${cart.key.tilte }"/></td>
                <td><c:out value = "${cart.key.price }"/></td>
                <c:set var = "price" value="${price}"></c:set>
                <c:set var="i" value = "${i+1 }"/>
            </tr>
         </c:forEach>
```

in this code snippet i want to access cartx which is a session variable and it contains list of book objects where book is a class.

i want to print the title and price of book which are the members of book class.

Comment: How exactly is hashmap related to this? Does `${cartx.items}` return a `List<Map<Book, V>>`? Your question description suggests that it is a `List<Book>`? This question can't be reliably answered without knowing the exact type of `${cartx.items}`.

Answer (score 1):

Maps are accessed in JSTL like that: `${map[key]}`. (if `key` is an attribute as well)